# How to work remotely as a multiuser enviroment on Xcode, deployed on a Mac mini server

Tags: macos, osx-server, remote-desktop

I have many windows and mac system users in my office & and mac users use Xcode for development. I have a mac mini server with 16GB RAM, i want to use it as a xcode server, means is that possible some way that multiple window or mac user connect that mac mini server, work on xcode and logout when ever he wants. I also tried screen sharing for mac users and vnc for windows system but both ways are very slow to respond. I heard somewhere like Xcode server i searched for it but didn't get is properly. Can xcode server solve my problem? Please suggest any idea.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that Xcode Server provides that functionality. Xcode Server (part of macosx server)  is a continuous integration solution, which means that your developers work on their own machines with their local tools and push code to a repo accessed by the Xcode server, which builds & tests the newly submitted code.

see [Xcode Continuous Integration](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/) for a far better explanation of the workflow.

I don't know of any solution (other than vnc/screen sharing) that will allow you to share the Xcode app on the server between multiple users.