# Xcode: shared build server?

Tags: xcode

Is it possible to setup a Mac as a server for shared builds?

Our environment at the moment has each developer using mid range macs for the entire development workflow. Our build times are creeping up, so we're looking at ways to speed them up. Buying better macs for all developers is the obvious way, but I'm wondering if it's possible to buy one super powerful mac and setup Xcode so all developers use that for their builds.

I know Xamarin/Visual Studio can be setup to use a remote mac for builds, but I don't know if that's possible in Xcode.

Specifically, what I want is when the developer hits build and run the code is sent to the build server which builds the app and returns the built app for the local xcode to install on the device. The code should not have to be checked in first.

Comment: It’s pretty common use case to use one fast Mac and use it as a build server. Multiple developers can share it.

Comment: @NimeshNeema Thanks, I can't find any official documentation about this though. Do you know of any?

Comment: You mean this: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/index.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to work remotely as a multiuser enviroment on Xcode, deployed on a Mac mini server](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254754/how-to-work-remotely-as-a-multiuser-enviroment-on-xcode-deployed-on-a-mac-mini)

Comment: @NimeshNeema I've found that but it doesn't seem to be what I need. That describes continuous integration, rather than being a normal part of the build workflow. Specifically, what I want is when the developer hits build and run the code is sent to the build server which builds the app and returns the built app for the local xcode to install on the device. The code should not have to be checked in first.

Comment: @IanNewson I would find hard to belive that would be quicker than a local compile. You should only have to recompile a few bits of code each time. Xcode also builds in the background so should have a small thing to do after a save. save.